# High idle when put in forward gear

Tags: idle, lincoln, continental

My 1992 Lincoln Continental Signature series 38000 miles. Revs up to about 1500-1700 when put in a forward gear, but not reverse? Help

Comment: Welcome to the site. Usually when I hear something like this, I wonder if the throttle linkage isn't being manipulated some how when the engine is put over in drive. Possibly one of the motor mounts has let lose, then when it's put into drive, the engine rolls over a little bit, which pulls on the linkage. Something to check out.

Comment: Do you have a CEL / trouble codes? A faulty IAT can cause this.

Comment: the rise in RPM's is caused by the Idle switch. I t has been replaced, first with after market then with factory unit. both times a relearn procedure was preformed. then had at the local auto electric guys for a week, even had a new factory PCM installed, Same thing. something is sending info to the Idle switch and engaging it, it stops when I unplug it.but later stalls at stops.